# Can I call an SQL Server's user defined function from Microsoft Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to upsize my Access application to an Access FE and a SQL Server database BE.

One of the problem I have is that queries with "filtering parameters" are executed client-side and require all rows to be sent from the server to the client.

example:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyId = Forms!MyForm!MyControl.Value;
```

This query will require all the rows from MyTable to be sent from the SQL Server to Access that will eventually execute the WHERE clause.

I've read about SQL Server's User Defined Function and it looks like it could work for me if only I could call them from Access the same way I can do in a SQL Server Query.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is MyID indexed? If so, then Access shouldn't be dragging the entire table across from the server.

I'm not sure where you're getting the criteria from, though, as that's not the SQL that a form filter is going to send. Or even a saved QueryDef with a hardwired reference to a control on a form.

Try dropping .Value (it's redundant as it's the default property).

Also, if it's a saved QueryDef, try defining the control reference as a parameter, i.e., `PARAMETERS Forms!MyForm!MyControl Long;`.

Basically, nothing that you report is standard Access behavior with ODBC linked tables to SQL Server. If it were, Access would be hell to upsize, and it's not at all.

Comment: Ok, I must admit I did not test this myself. I read somewhere online that Access would not send the WHERE to SQL server in this case. I'll try to test it myself If I can find a way to see what is Access sending to the server.

Comment: Jet/ACE is extremely smart about handing off data retrieval to the server. You can force it by giving it something the server can't do (like selecting on an Access UDF), but the SQL you posted shouldn't cause any problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with a "pass-through" query.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, a pass-through query will do it, but that will leave a persistent query object in your application window.

Using ADO recordset and connection objects will allow you to return filtered results into your recordset, but you'll need to write TSQL statements, which differ from Access SQL.

Comment: If you need to filter the returned data based on data from a control on an Access form, a passthrough is not going to get you anything you don't already have without it.

Comment: I've often dynamically built a sql string in TSQL (incorporating a form control's values), then updated a passthrough query's sql property. This passthrough query will give you a much faster response, since it bypasses the ODBC translation layer.